# jQuery UI Autocomplete with Categories

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, categories

I'm using jQuery UI's Auto Complete to provide suggestions from a remote source for a search input box.  I've got the "remote datasource" example working.  For example, this works:

```
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: "search_basic.php",
        minLength: 2
    });
```

However, I'd like to use the "[Categories](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories)" example to sort the suggesions by category.  The example from the jQuery UI site, with an inline set of data works fine:

```
       <script>
 $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
   var self = this,
    currentCategory = "";
   $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
    if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
     ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
     currentCategory = item.category;
    }
    self._renderItem( ul, item );
   });
  }
 });

 $(function() {
  var data = [
   { label: "anders", category: "" },
   { label: "andreas", category: "" },
   { label: "antal", category: "" },
   { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
   { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
   { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
   { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
   { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
   { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
  ];

  $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
   delay: 0,
   source: data
  });
 });
 </script>
```

However, when I try to get the data from my remote file

```
source: 'search.php'
```

it doesn't suggest anything.  Here's the code with the search.php:

```
    <script>
 $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
   var self = this,
    currentCategory = "";
   $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
    if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
     ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
     currentCategory = item.category;
    }
    self._renderItem( ul, item );
   });
  }
 });

 $(function() {

  $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
   source: 'search.php'
  });
 });
 </script>
```

The data that search.php is returning is correctly formatted:

```
         [
 { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
 { label: "annttop", category: "Products" },
 { label: "anders", category: "People" },
 { label: "andreas", category: "People" }
 ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 6):

Since I migrated to UI 1.10.2 my widget did'nt work !

Just a modification in the line :

```
self._renderItem( ul, item );
```

that becomes :

```
self._renderItemData( ul, item );
```

That works again !

Comment: This doesn't work in jQuery UI 1.11 render item data renders the html content of the field and doesn't solve the category issue

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP file probably isn't returning the right header. Add this to your PHP file:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

The browser will then interpret the response as JSON and act on it.

**EDIT:**

Your response also needs to have quotes around the labels, not just the values, when returning JSON in a response. 
In PHP, using `json_encode()` on an array of objects will return the following JSON (linebreaks added):

```
[
 { "label": "annhhx10", "category": "Products" },
 { "label": "annttop", "category": "Products" },
 { "label": "anders", "category": "People" },
 { "label": "andreas", "category": "People" }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Clay, I did forget the header in the search.php file, however, adding it didn't fixed the problem.

-Greg